# Gradle:where can I find some tutorials about gradle cache directory

Tags: gradle

That directory has some directories, such as jars-3, modules-2, transforms-1, etc.
In the modules-2, there exist files-2.1, metadata-2.53/metadata-2.59, etc
In the files-2.1, there exists the various downloaded packages.
In the metadata-2.53, there is the direcriptors directory, where various packages description info (descriptor.bin) resides.

Where can I find some user manual about this? What's the rule where one package is put? What if I want to copy one package from one computer to another? What's the content of descriptor.bin?

I have read the [gradle user manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.pdf) and [gradle user guide](http://downloads.gvsig.org/download/people/jjdelcerro/docs/Gradle%20User%20Guide.pdf), there is nearly nothing about this.

Answer (score 0):

The gradle user guide you linked is quite outdated.  As of gradle 6.1 there is a relocatable dependency cache and as of gradle 6.2 there is support for a shareable read-only dependency cache.

From the gradle 6.2.2 [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.2/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#sec:dependency_cache):

> **Copying and reusing the cache**
>
> The dependency cache, both the file and
>   metadata parts, are fully encoded using relative paths. This means
>   that it is perfectly possible to copy a cache around and see Gradle
>   benefit from it.
>
> The path that can be copied is $GRADLE_HOME/caches/modules-.
>   The only constraint is placing it using the same structure at the
>   destination, where the value of GRADLE_HOME can be different.

Comment: I am using gradle version 5.1.1, which is not quite outdated. In android development, that's a quite new version of gradle.